# Array out of Bounds in inserting a new Element

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new in Java and trying to learn how to manipulate Arrays. In this case, I'm trying to insert an Element in an Array in between the contained Elements. But I'm having an error saying,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at insert.main(insert.java:16)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks guys!

```
public class insert{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int LA[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
        int i = 0, j = n;
        
        //Display or Traverse an Array
        System.out.print("The original arrays are: \n");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
            }
            
            n = n + 1;
            
            while (j >= k) {
                LA[j+1] = LA[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            
            LA[k] = item;
            
            System.out.print("The new arrays are: \n");
            
            for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in Java are 0-indexed, your array only have 5 elements which means there is no 5th element. You can't insert at 5th position. And arrays have constant size, you can't just assign to `k+1` if array is of size `k`.

Comment: @Amongalen Can you elaborate it more clearly? :/

Comment: Welcome to SO! See https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp for getting started with arrays in java, and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html for a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `LA[j+1]`, which is equal to `LA[6]` in your case, but because `LA[]` only has 5 elements (which are numbered from 0 to 4), the exception is thrown, since you can't access an element that doesn't exist.

Additionally, it's not possible to modify the size of an `array` in Java. If you want to add an element you either have to instantiate a new `array`, or use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is, that Arrays have a length that can't be changed. And they also start at 0, which means that the 1st position in your array is 0, which would be `LA[0] = 10`. To get your code running you would need something like that:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int LA[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
        int j = n;

        //Display or Traverse an Array
        System.out.println("The original arrays are: ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
        }
        
        while (j >= k) {
            LA[j - 1] = LA[j - 1];
            j -= 1;
        }

        LA[k] = item;

        System.out.println("The new arrays are: ");

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to insert something in an array, I would recommend not using Arrays at all but ArrayLists. You could then do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        
        //Creating the ArrayList to accept Integers
        List LA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            //adding numbers from 10 to 50 to the list
            LA.add(i * 10);
        }

        //Display or Traverse an Array
        System.out.println("The original arrays are: ");
        
        //LA.size() is practically the same as any array.length, you don't need a variable to do this
        for(int i = 0; i < LA.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA.get(i));
        }

        //adding 60 (duh)
        LA.add(60);

        System.out.println("The new arrays are: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < LA.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first snippet you got `LA[j - 1] = LA[j - 1];` - which obviously doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes, you're right but it's the only thing that didn't work and I didn't know what he was trying to get with this, he had tons of unnamed variables without any explanation of what they do, so I did what I could do.